# Grammatik in "als wir, die wir uns ... nach Freiheit gesehnt hatten, zum ersten Mal demonstrierten"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Aus [Joachim Gaucks Rede am 9. Oktober](http://www.bundespraesident.de/SharedDocs/Reden/DE/Joachim-Gauck/Reden/2014/10/141009-Rede-zur-Demokratie.html):

> Es war erhebend, als wir, **die wir uns ein ganzes Leben lang nach Freiheit gesehnt hatten**, zum ersten Mal demonstrierten.

Funktioniert

> die wir uns ein ganzes Leben lang nach Freiheit gesehnt hatten

als ein Relativsatz? Es ist nicht klar, **was** diese Phrase beschreibt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es handelt sich in der Tat um einen Relativsatz. Mein Grammatik-Duden (Paragraph 1289) sagt dazu:

> Wenn sich ein Relativpronomen (als Subjekt des Relativsatzes) auf ein Personalpronomen der 1. oder 2. Person bezieht, wird normalerweise nach dem Relativpronomen die passende Nominativform des Personalpronomens eingefügt:
>
> > **Wir, die *wir* immer vor zu engen Beziehungen gewarnt haben, werden nun mit angegriffen.**
>
> Das Finitum des Relativsatzes sowie vorkommende Reflexiv- oder Possessivpronomen kongruieren dann mit dem Personalpronomen (nicht mit dem Relativpronomen):
>
> > **Ich, der ich in dieser Situation *mein* Bestes versucht *habe* ... [...]**
>
> [...] Weglassung des Personalpronomens kommt aber durchaus häufiger vor [...]:
>
> > **Was kann *ich* tun, der *ich* krank und hilflos *bin*?** (Auch möglich:) **Was kann *ich* tun, *der* krank und hilflos *ist*?**

<sup>Der **Fettdruck** obiger Beispielsätze ist von mir; die *Kursivsetzung* einzelner Wörter stammt vom Duden selbst.</sup>

---

Betrachten wir nun deinen/Gaucks Relativsatz:

> ... die ***wir*** ***uns*** ein ganzes Leben lang nach Freiheit gesehnt ***hatten*** ...

Weil sich das Relativpronomen (*die*) auf die 1. Person Plural (*wir*) des übergeordneten Satzes bezieht, wird das Personalpronomen (*wir*) im Relativsatz wiederholt. Beim Verb *sich sehnen* wird das Reflexivpronomen (*sich*) an das Personalpronomen angepasst und zu *uns*. Das finite Verb (*hatten*) richtet sich dabei nach dem Personalpronomen (*wir*, 1. Person Plural) und nicht nach dem Relativpronomen (*die*, 3. Person Plural), obwohl man den Unterschied natürlich nicht bemerkt, weil beide Formen gleich sind (*die ... hatten* vs. *wir ... hatten*). Würde man den Relativsatz ohne *wir* formulieren, müsste er

> ... die ***sich*** ein ganzes Leben lang nach Freiheit gesehnt ***hatten*** ...

lauten, wobei sich dann Reflexivpronomen (*sich*) und finites Verb (*hatten*) am Relativpronomen der 3. Person Plural (*die*) orientieren würden.

Comment: Die Qualität der Antworten ist heute Abend hoch. Hat denn niemand am Freitagabend besseres zu tun? ;)