# Relative clause with personal pronoun: "wir..., die wir..." for non-reflexive verbs

Tags: relative-clause, reflexive

I've seen that often, together with the relative pronoun, a personal pronoun appears, both in nominative:

> e.g. (…) und wir, die **wir** als Arbeiter gemeint waren, hatten Spaß.

Is this *wir* a double subject? Is it emphasizing the relative *die*? I guess it's allowed, as allowed as it would be not to write it. Is there any difference? Is reflexivity needed in order for this nominative duplication be valid?

How about pronouns which would lead to a conjugation-ambiguity?

> e.g. (…) wohingegen ich, der ich das gegessen habe/hat, satt war.

Comment: Do you have any resources for these phrases? It's very unusual to use a personal pronoun in a subordinate clause, **if** the pronoun is already clear from context.

Comment: @Nadim' What would be the sources for? To judge correctness according to author? I'm aware that it is unusual. Otherwise I wouldn’t have asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grammatik in "als wir, die wir uns ... nach Freiheit gesehnt hatten, zum ersten Mal demonstrierten"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18157/grammatik-in-als-wir-die-wir-uns-nach-freiheit-gesehnt-hatten-zum-ersten)

Comment: @tofro so, reflexivity is not essential, is it? The putative dupe didn't show up when I typed. Perhaps because I typed English. Usually the same question is allowed in both languages, without being a dupe. So, I'll leave mine here.

Comment: In my "Sprachgefühl", reflexity *is* somewhat essential. Note the linked question also quotes a reflexive relative clause. As far as Duden seems to disagree (didn't bother to look it up, however), I removed my comment, though ;) . And I was somewhat surprised as well that this question has been asked before. GSE seems to already cover a lot of ground, more than I thought.

Comment: Note "...wir, die *sich* nach Freiheit gesehnt hatten..." sounds wierd and worse than "...wir, die wir uns nach Freiheit gesehnt hatten..." to me, but "...wir, die als Arbeiter gemeint waren..." sounds pretty much acceptable and doesn't need the double pronoun. Both forms are correct, however. Matter of taste, maybe?

Comment: Thanks, @tofro. My Sprachgefühl is still no good reference. Thus, I'll accept the `rel. pronoun`+`pers. pronoun`-form as normal when I read and ban it, when I write (without reflexive).

Comment: @tofro To **not** handle questions in different languages as duplicates is one of the [clearest community votes on Meta](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei) that I can recall. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @Matthias Ich nehme ziemlich of gar nicht wahr, dass ein Duplikat in der jeweils anderen Sprache verfasst ist - Vote zurückgezogen.

Comment: @tofro Geht mir ähnlich. Habe sogar schon ganze Antworten übersetzt, weil ich erst kurz vor dem Speichern gemerkt habe, dass ich sie in der "falschen" Sprache verfasst habe.

Comment: \*hust\* Gut, dass du mich auch noch darauf aufmerksam gemacht hast, @Matthias ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is perfectly fine, and indeed does not lead to conjugation ambiguity, but resolves a conjugation awkwardness.

> ... ich, der das gesehen hat, ...

is maybe correct (I am not sure), but at least confusing, because *hat* does not correspond to *ich*.

> ... ich, der ich das gesehen habe, ...

does not have this problem.

Comment: This does not answer the main question, i.e. the question about the first sentence, where this amiguity of the verb conjugation does not exist. The verb would be "hatten" even without the second "wir".

Answer (score 0):

The main clause in the sentence is:

"Und wir hatten Spaß."

The rest of the sentence is a subordinate clause that acts as a "parenthetval" in the sentence: (die wir als Arbeiter gemeint waren),"

This is a perfectly acceptable construction.